# Can't connect to local web server from Android device

Tags: android, python, networking, webserver, cherrypy

I've connected my Android phone to my laptop using Connectify.

I have a `cherrypy` web server running on `192.168.210.1:8080`:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld:
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

It works on my laptop, but when I try to put `192.168.1.8080` in my Android, there's no response and it keeps waiting indefinitely. I tried pinging to the IP from my phone, and it works, showing replies.

I also tried turning Windows Firewall off - it instanantly results in the message *"Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.210.1:8080"*. If I start it again, it's back to the previous state.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the socket on which the server is listen to '0.0.0.0', by default is bound to `localhost`, to do that just change the `quickstart` call, with this config:

```
config = {'global': 
            {'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'}
}
quickstart(HelloWorld(), config=config)
```